# Apache Camel: Quotes will break the URI

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I have a problem with a simple Apache Camel HTTP->Python->HTTP route.

The goal is to set up a Camel route that accepts two factors of a multiplication using JSON. The format looks like this: `{"a":5,"b":5}`

The passed JSON object should then be passed to a Python script in which the product of the two factors is calculated and then the result is returned as a JSON object.

When I make a POST request to Camel and pass the above JSON to the body, I get an error message in Camel.

```
14:33:33.474 [Restlet-698774930] ERROR org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecProducer - The command ExecCommand [args=[src/main/resources/post.py, RAW({, a, :1,, b, :100})], executable=python, timeout=9223372036854775807, outFile=null, workingDir=null, useStderrOnEmptyStdout=false] returned exit value 1
```

The problem seems to be the quotes.
These ensure that the JSON object is not recognized as one argument, but is split into several arguments.

In Camel's documentation you will find something about "[RAW()](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html)", which does not work in this case.

Of course, the Python script dies because the second argument is not a JSON object. But if you run it manually from the command line it works without problems. This means that the error is not in the script but in the call by Camel.

```
package com.sample.simplecalc;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  public void configure() throws Exception{

    restConfiguration()
    .component("restlet")
    .host("localhost").port("8080")
    .enableCORS(false)
    ;

    rest().path("/api").produces("application/json").consumes("application/json")
    .get()
        .toD("exec:python?args=src/main/resources/get.py")
    .post()
        .toD("exec:python?args=src/main/resources/post.py RAW(${body})");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to marshal the message body as JSON before passing it to the script.

```
.post()
    .marshal().json()
    .toD("exec:python...")
```

See the [Camel JSON page](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/json.adoc) for options dependencies etc.